# How To get value in [[ ]]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

example

```
import pandas as pd  
b = [[300, 200, 100, 10]] #(data which pass from upper side so cant edit)

data_dict = {'value': pd.Series(b)}
dframe = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
dframe
     value
0   [300, 200, 100,10]
```

How to make the number show on each row?
like below

```
   value
0 [300]
1 [200]
2 [100]
3 [10]
```

Comment: Your code throws "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'module' and 'type'", I know it's trivial but could you please ensure your minimal example at least runs?

Comment: `{'value': pd.Series(b[0])}` should work right? Since it's a nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
dframe.explode('value').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
  value
0   300
1   200
2   100
3    10
```